# how to retrieve value from text file using python?

Tags: python, file-io, python-2.7

```
import re
sum=0
file = open("pro.txt").readlines()
for lines in file:
        word= len(re.findall('(^|[^\w\-])able#1(?=([^\w\-]|$))', lines))
        if word>0:
                sum=sum+1
```

pro.txt

```
0         6          9     able#1
0         11         34    unable#1
9         12         22    able#1
0         6          9     able#1-able#1
0         11         34    unable#1*able#1
```

i want to get the value of the word , like if user enter the sentence and it contain word able than it retrieve the values against it like `9 6 0` or `0 6 9` , but now as a sample i just want that if i focus on only able#1 word in this txt file how can i retrieve values through it , as i am just trying it in a way to split it and than just put queue on it

```
for lines in file:
    k=lines.split()
    print k


['0', '6', '9', 'able#1', 'you#1']
['0', '11', '34', 'unable#1']
['9', '12', '22', 'able#1']
['0', '6', '9', 'able#1-able#1']
['0', '11', '34', 'unable#1*able#1']
['9', '12', '22', 'able#1_able#1']
```

Expected output:

```
enter the word you want to find in text file : able#1
word found !!
values are
0         6          9
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
s = "able#1"

for line in open("pro.txt").readlines():
    if s == line.split()[3].strip():
        print line.rsplit(' ',1)[0].strip()
```

**Output**

```
>>> 
0         6          9
9         12         22
```

---

If you need only one space between the numbers, then use this:

```
print ' '.join(line.split()[:3])
```

**Update**

Complete code:

```
s = raw_input("enter the word you want to find in text file : ")

f = False
for line in open("pro.txt").readlines():
    if s == line.split()[3].strip():
        if not f:
            print "word found !!"
            f = True
        print ' '.join(line.split()[:3])
```

**Output**

```
>>> 
enter the word you want to find in text file : able#1
word found !!
0 6 9
9 12 22
>>>
```

Comment: i want to know it , if i found the word which are infront of values , so first it must find the word than values against it

Comment: What is your output going to be? Do you need to get the 1 in #1?

Comment: no , if i want to search the word able#1 in my text file , if the word exists then it print the values against that word

Comment: So, you need the value as `0 6 9` and `9 12 22`?

Answer (score 0):

```
for line in file:
    print line.split()[:3]
```

You'll get the first three elements of each line, e.g. ['0', '6', '9'].

If you want to look up the 3 numbers by word, you can first build a dictionary with the contents of the file.

```
counts_by_word = dict((line[3], line[:3]) for line in file)
print counts_by_word["able#1"]
# Output: ['9', '12', '22']
```